What Does Mean of "Class::Class() : _x(1), _y(2) { begin(); }"
I know OOP a little bit in different languages, but i don't know how it's work below (Code 1) code. Both codes are same right? If it is why do we use Code 1 instead of Code 2?
Code 1:
ClassExample::ClassExample() : 
_x(1), 
_y(2) 
{ 
begin(0); 
}

Code 2:
ClassExample::ClassExample()
{
_x = 1;
_y = 2; 
begin(0); 
}

I don't know how to look this up online so I had to ask you.

Google "member initializer list".

no, they are not the same. Depending on what x and y are, the two are potentially totally different. You can look this up by reading about constructors: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor. Any introduction to constructors should mention the member initializer list. Don't worry, this is perhaps the most basic most important detail that most beginners miss.

I would also recommend a good c++ book

The distinction between initialization and assignment is very important in C++. Don't assume that languages work the same just because they look similar on the surface.

Unless the identifier Class has a VERY specific meaning (which you haven't stated, so we don't know) then the first sample of code is gibberish.    The second is a definition of a constructor for a class named CanControllerClass that accepts no arguments, assigns _x (whatever it is) to the value 1, _y with the value 2, and  then does begin(0)   (the meaning of which depends on what begin is, which again you have not stated, but it could be calling a function with argument 0, calling an operator() of an object with argument 0, or a range of other possibilities).

Try with ClassExample { int const _x; int const _y; ClassExample(); }.  Code 2 doesn't work.
